# can't verify emails in Parse

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform

I've turned on email verification in my Parse account, but no emails are being sent.

a) I've successfully signed up two private email accounts (using Javascript API), and neither receives an email.

b) The Users are created properly, but the emailVerified field is set to "undefined", shouldn't it be false?

d) I've tried setting emailVerified to false programmatically, and saving the user, but no verification email.

e) I've tried changing the user's email in the Parse data viewer, but no email.

Any suggestions? I recently tested password recovery and it works fine.

Here is my code.

```
function psSignup(roleName, email, password, company, domain, firstName, lastName, phone, position, referralName, referralSource) {
  // Always log out to clear old sessions before we sign in new user.
  Parse.User.logOut();    

  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", email);
  user.set("password", password);
  user.set("firstName", firstName);
  user.set("lastName", lastName);
  user.set("phone", phone);
  user.set("company", company);
  user.set("position", position);
  user.set("referralName", referralName);
  user.set("referralSource", referralSource);

  // Signup asynch
  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) { 
      var queryRole = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
      queryRole.equalTo('name', roleName);
      queryRole.first({
        success: function(result) { 
          // Assign users role for security purposes.
          var role = result;
          role.getUsers().add(user);
          role.save().then(function() {
            // Create acount, link to user, save account
            var account = psMakeAccount(company, user, domain);
            return account.save();
          }).then(function(accountObject) {
            // link to user
            user.set("account", accountObject);
            user.save();
          }).then(function(userObject) {
            // Success Go to second login page.
            document.location.href = "/signup/location-information/";
          }, function(error) {
            messageAlert("Signup", "Failed to save objects with error: " + error.message);
          });
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
      messageAlert("Signup", "Signup error: " + error.message);
    }
  });
}
```